# Remix online editor - set tab width

Tags: remix

The tab width on remix https://remix.ethereum.org defaults to 4 spaces. I have looked everywhere but I cannot see how to change it to 2 spaces, or 3 or whatever. Is it possible?

nb: don't care what the standards are, try working on a 13 inch laptop.

Comment: Have you tried the new layout? You can hide the file explorer tab.

Comment: Try out the gitter channel of remix: https://gitter.im/ethereum/remix

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree, however, there is no "standard" when it comes to layout. Four tabs is a complete waste of space!!! It's also about readability. The '}' arrangement is a programmer preference, NOT a "standard".